# Fraud.signature

Tags: signature

A simliar question was asked about frauding over a signature.
My question is what if they copy and pasted your signature to a contract.of course the person has proof that this signature was done fraudlent.would it be a criminal case or other.I wanted to go civil lawsuit.but I also have fraud in there also.since someone .copy and pasted my signature to a contract of obligation of paying a bill.

Comment: This could be a case in both civil and criminal courts. You should specify your jurisdiction, but generally speaking, in civil court you would get a compensation from the defendant --including what is known as *punitive and exemplary damages*--, whereas in criminal court the defendant might end up being sentenced to prison.

Comment: Would I have to report it to local police to get the ball rolling or go to the courthouse and file a case against them?

Comment: In civil court you can file a lawsuit by yourself, whereas --at least in the US-- only the Attorney General (AG) via a prosecutor can press charges against the defendant. In many jurisdictions of the US, though, people do not have access to the AG. Instead, they report the fraud to the police.

Comment: Well it's a local government owned utilities department that forged my signature..kinda complicated what do you suggest?

Comment: The level of detail in your inquiry is very insufficient to make any suggestions on how to proceed, especially since it involves a local government and you yourself point out that it is complicated.

Comment: Well the municipality utilities department forged my signature on a payment arrangement document, and the reason I stated it was complicated is because it's owned by the town, aka the local government, so how would I proceed? File a suit against the whole of the city or the utility department or should I press for criminal charges since it is a local government, in either case would I need to solo somebody out for accountability or what?

Answer (score 1):

Before you file a lawsuit, check whether the legislature in your jurisdiction requires any *exhaustion of administrative remedies*. If so, proceed accordingly, *prior to* filing a complaint in court. The legislation would also specify whether a complaint against the city shall be filed in a specific court or venue. Most likely you would have to sue the city.

Although unlikely, if you have identified specific individuals as responsible for the forgery, you might want to list them as defendants as well. Based on the context, you will need to identify whether you are suing these individuals in their official or personal capacity.

If you decide to proceed in court, be mindful that you will be required to establish through evidence that your signature was forged. Although you state that

> of course the person has proof that this signature was done fraudlent

(which I assume that by "*the person*" you mean yourself) your case seemingly requires a rather complex analysis of factual circumstances. Since you have provided almost no context and no details on how this happened, it is impossible to make any suggestions on how to accomplish that.

Regardless of whether you opt to pursue the matter in civil court, you might also want to report with the police that your signature has been forged. Also there it is crucial that you provide sufficient, relevant information, lest the police dismiss the matter as too vague or too unpersuasive to conduct an investigation.